# What file am I missing to be able to boot into Xubuntu through Grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu

So I am trying to install Xubuntu into my EliteBook 6930p and while I did do it with success, one thing is still stopping me from using it: *the fact that a file is missing*.
To solve this problem, which file do I need in my USB drive to be able to boot into Xubuntu and use it?

Xubuntu I am attempting to use is LTS 20.04

I have successfully installed Xubuntu including Grub, but when I try to boot into it it fails to find said file and decides to not boot

Comment: Welcome to this site! But it would help to know exactly what 
you're seeing that leads you to say that a file is missing. See more tips on helping us help you at https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you want the Xubuntu for? And why the USB stick?

Comment: MaestroGlanz: As a system to replace my EliteBook's preinstalled system (Win7, out of support), and the USB stick because it was a valid way to install Xubuntu